# Como alinhar o resultado do Select

Tags: sql, sql-select

Estou elaborando um relatório, onde pego o nome de uma pessoa, e quais dias ela trabalha. Consegui fazer esse select, porém preciso que o resulto fique dessa forma:

> ```
> [JOÃO - SEG/QUART]
> [MARIA - TERÇ/QUINT]
> [JOSÉ - SEG/TER/QUART]
> ```

Usei o (xmlagg), mas não ta dando certo.

```
select DISTINCT 
    Substr(Obter_nome_medico(ag.CD_PESSOA_FISICA,'N'), 1, 100) nm_medico,
    rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,substr(obter_valor_dominio(35,at.ie_dia_semana),1,1000),';').extract('//text()')),';')
from TABELA1 a, TABELA2 ag, TABELA3 at
where Substr(Obter_nome_medico(ag.CD_PESSOA_FISICA, 'N'), 1, 100) is not null 
and a.cd_agenda = ag.CD_AGENDA 
and ag.cd_agenda = at.cd_agenda 
group by Substr(Obter_nome_medico(ag.CD_PESSOA_FISICA,'N'), 1, 100);
```

Comment: e como o retorno está agora ?

Comment: ORA-19011: O buffer de strings de caracteres é muito pequeno
19011. 00000 -  "Character string buffer too small" 
*Cause:    The string result asked for is too big to return back
*Action:   Get the result as a lob instead

Comment: você pode [Edit] a pergunta e adicionar as informações necessárias. Pelo visto você está usando Oracle ? se sim, adicione nas tags

Comment: oracle ? Tentou usar o LISTAGG ? https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030